# Entity Framework error : Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement Entity Framework code-first approach, but I get an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.StateMasters_dbo.CountryMasters_CountryRefId' on table
>   'StateMasters' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.

This is my EF code. Simply to insert record in database.

Domain classes:

```
public class CountryMaster
{
    public CountryMaster()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck, Required, MaxLength(50), MinLength(2)]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<StateMaster> States { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CityMaster> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class StateMaster
{
    public StateMaster()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int StateCode { get; set; }

    public int CountryRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountryRefId")]
    public CountryMaster Country { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck, Required, MaxLength(50), MinLength(2)]
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    //  public ICollection<CityMaster> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class CityMaster
{
     public CityMaster()
     {
     }

     [Key]
     public int CityCode { get; set; }

     public int CountryRefId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("CountryRefId")]
     public CountryMaster Country { get; set; }

     public int StateRefId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("StateRefId")]
     public StateMaster State { get; set; }

     [ConcurrencyCheck, Required, MaxLength(50), MinLength(2)]
     public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

Repository interface:

```
public interface I_COUNTRY_STATE_CITYRepository:IDisposable
{
    void InsertCountry(CountryMaster Country);
    void SaveCountry();
}
```

Repository implementation:

```
public class COUNTRY_STATE_CITYRepository : IDisposable, I_COUNTRY_STATE_CITYRepository
{
    private COUNTRY_STATE_CITYContext context;

    public COUNTRY_STATE_CITYRepository(COUNTRY_STATE_CITYContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void InsertCountry(CountryMaster Country)
    {
        context.Countries.Add(Country);
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }

        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void SaveCountry()
    {
         context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Context class :

```
public class COUNTRY_STATE_CITYContext: DbContext
{
     public COUNTRY_STATE_CITYContext() : base("ConnectionString")
     { }

     public DbSet<CountryMaster> Countries { get; set; }
     public DbSet<StateMaster> States { get; set; }
     public DbSet<CityMaster> Cities { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<CountryMaster>().HasMany(i => i.States).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
     }
 }
```

C# code is to simply pass value of country name and insert into the database :

```
public partial class CheckCountryStateCity : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var ctx = new COUNTRY_STATE_CITYContext())
        {
            COUNTRY_STATE_CITYRepository wr = new                  COUNTRY_STATE_CITYRepository(ctx);
            CountryMaster wt = new CountryMaster();

            wt.CountryName = "ABC";
            wr.InsertCountry(wt);
            wr.SaveCountry();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Existing records with foreign key in some tables.So when you trying to remove such data it causing error.

Solution :
If you want to delete referenced data on Parent Record delete then you should mention Cascade delete in database.

OR

You have to restrict user while deleting referenced records.

Comment: Actually first time database is going to create so there are no tables in database.